# How do you return error messages from AJAX calls using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

If I have an ASP.NET MVC controller action that is called from a jQuery .ajax call that needs to throw an error, how do I do so?  I know I can create a JSON object and pass it an "error" property, but what if the response from the .ajax call isn't expected to be JSON but HTML instead?

Comment: so did this turn out to be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the HandleError attribute, and set View to a view which returns the appropriate HTML fragment.

```
[HandleError(View="AjaxErrorFragment")]
public ActionResult ICallThisWithjQuery() {
```